# Ubuntu 20.04 no network connectivity

Tags: networking, netplan

The computer is Kubuntu 20.04.
I can't connect to internal network, over WiFi or cable.
It gets dhcp address and fw shows activity, but ping doesn't work.
I've tried to erase all wifi connections and adding with no luck.
Although i could pair to my phone ap and get internet.

All other devices in the network work as expected.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the output of `lshw -C network`, `ip a`, and `route -n`? This will show some details about your network cards and the connections, which might make it easier for someone to help out 

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your help. After two days it started working again. I don't know exactly what was the problem. I rearranged cabling at the switch and also noticed that ntp settings in the switch where "reverted?" to somewhere in china.
I was algo having a simmilar problem with a Unifi Ap and also got resolved at the same time.

The resolv.conf file was showing a weird ip like 127.0.0.255 as the dns server.